# Derivatives of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, simplifying-expressions, trigonometry

Let's use the following sample case

```
Clear["Global`*"];

t1 = ArcTan[y/(x - x1)];
f = (3*(Cos[t1])^2 - 1);

der = D[f, x]
```

which gives

```
(6 y^2)/((x - x1)^3 (1 + y^2/(x - x1)^2)^2)
```

My question is: how can we simplify the result since some parts of the resulted equation correspond to the trigonometric function `Sin[t1]`?

Comment: So what you want is basically `D[3*(Cos[t1])^2 - 1, t1]/D[x1 + y Cot[t1], t1]`, no?

Comment: @J.M. I don't understand your point. I just want to simplify the result by appearing sin(t1).

Comment: ...and the result of the snippet I gave has `Sin[t1]` in it; I merely used the chain rule manually.

Comment: Consider the function f which you differentiate.This is NOT a trigonometric  function, and hence I do not understand why you are expecting Mathematica to do something like that for you.

Comment: @DiSp0sablE_H3r0 Function f contains Cos(...), so when I compute the derivative of f I expect a Sin(...) to appear.

Comment: "Function `f` contains `Cos`" - but composing it with `ArcTan` yields an algebraic function. So, you'd need to take a different route (like in my first comment).

Comment: Maybe I said it too quickly. You have the composition of two trig functions. The final result is a fraction of polynomials. While I do understand what you say, I was merely trying to suggest that you should consider what @J.M. proposed and ask Mathematica to do something for you in a different way

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, the use of "Simplify" is here misleading. I guess that you would like to make variables change.  If so, try the following:

Step 1:

```
t1 = ArcTan[y/(x - x1)];
f = (3*(Cos[t1])^2 - 1);
der = D[f, x]
(*  (6 y^2)/((x - x1)^3 (1 + y^2/(x - x1)^2)^2)  *)
```

Step 2:

```
rule = y -> (x - x1)*Tan[t];
der2=Simplify[der /. rule, t \[Element] Reals]

(* (6 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2)/(x - x1) *)
```

Then you may still transform it into a few other forms if you find them advantageous. For example,

```
TrigReduce[der2]

(*  -((3 (-1 + Cos[4 t]))/(4 (x - x1)))  *)
```

or

```
TrigToExp[der2] // Together

(*  -((3 E^(-4 I t) (-1 + E^(4 I t))^2)/(8 (x - x1)))  *)
```

Or like this:

```
rule2 = Cos[t] -> Sin[2 t]/(2 Sin[t]);

(6 Cos[t]^2 Sin[t]^2)/(x - x1) /. rule2

(*  (3 Sin[2 t]^2)/(2 (x - x1))   *)
```

I hope that's what you are after.

Have fun!